# Using tidyr top_n to select by a variable and include NAs

Tags: r, sorting, dplyr

I'm trying to use dplyr to group by a variable and identify the nearest location for every place in my dataset. I would also like to include all rows for which distance has not been measured (NA).

```r
# Set up df of place, distance, and destination.
df <- data.frame(place = c('A','B','B','C','C','D','D'),dist = c(NA, 4, 1, 6, 3, 1, 1), dest = 1:7)

# For each place, get the nearest destination. 
df %>% 
  group_by(place) %>%
  top_n(1, desc(dist))

# This does not return a row for place A.
```

Is there a tidyr solution for using top_n to identify rows based on rank that will also include rows that have not been ranked? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Could there be cases where `place` could have > 1 value for `dist`, where some values are NA and some are not? If so, what should be returned for those cases?

Answer (score 0):

This works but there are probably more efficient solutions.

The `coalesce(dist, max(dist), ...)` is there because we prioritize non-null values. Then, we want to make sure that a random value doesn't end up in top_n, so we take the `max(dist)` of the group. Then finally, to actually return a value, I put a number in - you could use any number.

If you were doing non-desc, you would likely use `min(dist)` instead of `max(dist)`.

```
df %>% 
  group_by(place) %>%
  top_n(1, desc(coalesce(dist, max(dist)+1, 0)))

  place  dist  dest
  <fct> <dbl> <int>
1 A        NA     1
2 B         1     3
3 C         3     5
4 D         1     6
5 D         1     7
```